# SBT: specify which app to test:run

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there a way to specify which app to run instead of having it ask me?

```
> test:run

Multiple main classes detected

[1] junk.Hi
[2] junk.Ho
[3] junk.Hey

Enter number:
```

I tried doing this, but it didn't help:

```
> set mainClass in (Compile, test) := Some("junk.Ho")
```

And this doesn't work (presumably) because the app to run is in the test sources:

```
> runMain junk.Ho
[info] Running junk.Ho
[error] (run-main) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junk.Ho
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
>test:runMain junk.Ho
```